printing decision tree as an image in python
I have written a decision tree class in Python which uses the Node class as tree nodes, as shown below:
class Node:
    '''
    Helper class which implements a single tree node.
    '''
    def __init__(self, feature=None, threshold=None, data_left=None, data_right=None, gain=None, value=None):
        self.feature = feature
        self.threshold = threshold
        self.data_left = data_left
        self.data_right = data_right
        self.gain = gain
        self.value = value

Now, I want to write a print method for this tree to print the gain, feature name, and threshold for each node of this tree, and print the value for leaf nodes, which represents the final label of the input sample.
Which libraries can I use for printing this output trained tree in an image format? How do I use them?
If I don’t want to print this tree in image format, which algorithm can I use to print it in a readable way with the information that I mentioned earlier?
I have written my print method as below! but it is not readable at all:
  def print_tree(self,node,depth=0):
      if node is None:
        return
      prefix = "    " * depth
    # If the node is a leaf node, print its value
      if node.value is not None:
        print(f"{prefix}Value: {node.value}")
      else:
        # Print the feature and threshold for the split at this node
        print(f"{prefix}Feature: {node.feature}, Threshold: {node.threshold}")
        # Recursively print the left and right subtrees
        print(f"{prefix}--> Left:")
        self.print_tree(node.data_left, depth + 1)
        print(f"{prefix}--> Right:")
        self.print_tree(node.data_right, depth + 1)


I use Graphviz and its DOT language for drawing graphs https://graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html .
You can convert dot-file to pdf with a command
dot -Tpdf dot_file.dot -o out_name.pdf

